# Showing if a user is online or offline php

Tags: php

I am showing a list of all the users from my database but i want to show next to each user name if the user is online or offline, using a while.
Right now it's only showing offline after each user, while i am online myself.

```
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stage_users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log))
{
   echo '<tr>
  <td class="qty"><a href="profiel.php?acc='.$row['Naam'].'">'.$row['Naam'].'</td>';

    $upda = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `stage_inloggen` 
    WHERE Seen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
    AND `Gebruikersnaam` = '$name' LIMIT 1 ");

    $num_rowst = mysql_fetch_array($upda);
    $count = $num_rowst[0];
    if($count!=0)
    {
        echo '<td class="stock in">Online</td>';
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<td class="stock out">Offline</td>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are missing $ symbol here `'row['Naam']'");`, it should be `'$row['Naam']'");`

Comment: what problem you are getting here?

Comment: @krishna it's showing offline next to each user even when i'm online (checked the DB)

Comment: please make sure that `Seen` is of Time type in table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$log = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stage_users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($log))
{
   $name = $row['Naam'];
   echo '<tr>
  <td class="qty"><a href="profiel.php?acc='.$name.'">'.$name.'</td>';

    $upda = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `stage_inloggen` WHERE Seen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
    AND `Gebruikersnaam` = '$name' LIMIT 1 ");

    $num_rowst = mysql_fetch_array($upda);
    $count = $num_rowst[0];
    if($count!=0)
    {

        echo '<td class="stock in">Online</td>';

    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td class="stock out">Offline</td>';
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, i tried your code but now it's showing offline after each user while i myself am online.

Comment: are you want to check `seen>10 minutes`

Comment: Yes, if a user is inactive for more than 10 min he will be set to offline, every time he goes to another page an update query will be issued to set to last seen to now, i checked my DB and that is still working fine, my last time seen is updated but it's still showing offline...

Comment: and r u storing time in your seen field? if yes what is the format of this an example please?

Comment: Solved! The last problem was, in my query you changed AND `Gebruikersnaam` = '$row[Naam]'"); to $name while i didn't have the var $name. Thanks for your help!!